# What's wrong with this code

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am getting the compiler error. Can anybody debug this?

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
public class SendMail
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    SendMail sm=new SendMail();
     sm.postMail("abc@yahoo.com","hi","hello","xyz@gmail.com");
   }

public void postMail( String recipients[ ], String subject, String message , String from) throws MessagingException
{
    boolean debug = false;

     //Set the host smtp address
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", "webmail.emailmyname.com");

    // create some properties and get the default Session
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    // create a message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // set the from and to address
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

    InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
    {
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
    }
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);


    // Optional : You can also set your custom headers in the Email if you Want
    msg.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");

    // Setting the Subject and Content Type
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
    Transport.send(msg);
}
}
```

Comment: What compiler Error ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, javacode!  Could you be more specific about what compiler error you're getting, and where it occurs?

Comment: Heh, I was able to debug the code block formatting, at least :)

Comment: Could be the classpath is missing required jars, e.g., javamail.jar and java activation framework jar

Comment: Have you done any troubleshooting? Debugging? Are you running this in an IDE? I'd recommend editing your question to add more information.

Comment: @javacode: Downloads are at http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/downloads/index.html and usage instructions are at http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/FAQ.html#install

Answer (score 4):

Your `postMail` function is expecting the first parameter, `recipients` to be an array of Strings, but in your main method you are passing a String literal. The compiler is telling you that it's unable to find a version of the `postMail` method that matches a parameter-list like `(String, String, String, String)`.

Try calling it like this instead:

```
sm.postMail(new String[]{"abc@yahoo.com"},"hi","hello","xyz@gmail.com");
```

Another idea would be to make an overloaded version of your postMail method if this is something you intend to do often.

Comment: Note that you'll have to handle the MessagingException around the call to `postMail()` after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've included `mail.jar` and `activation.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: I have included both in classpath

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the main class in the [manifest file](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/run.html).